# SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad doesn't work on Ubuntu 20.04 on dynabook

Tags: 20.04, touchpad, synaptics

I installed Ubuntu 20.04 on dynabook GX83. My Touchpad is not working at all however the USB mouse is working correctly. Though I'd like to use the Touchpad. I searched and tried a lot of commands but I could not solve this problem.

What I tried and the results are as follows.

~ $xinput

```
︙
 ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad               id=15   [slave  pointer  (2)]
︙
```

~ $xinput list 15

```
SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                  id=15   [slave  pointer  (2)]
    Reporting 7 classes:
        Class originated from: 15. Type: XIButtonClass
        Buttons supported: 7
        Button labels: "Button Left" "Button Middle" "Button Right" "Button Wheel Up" "Button Wheel Down" "Button Horiz Wheel Left" "Button Horiz Wheel Right"
        Button state:
        Class originated from: 15. Type: XIValuatorClass
        Detail for Valuator 0:
          Label: Rel X
          Range: -1.000000 - -1.000000
          Resolution: 0 units/m
          Mode: relative
        Class originated from: 15. Type: XIValuatorClass
        Detail for Valuator 1:
          Label: Rel Y
          Range: -1.000000 - -1.000000
          Resolution: 0 units/m
          Mode: relative
        Class originated from: 15. Type: XIValuatorClass
        Detail for Valuator 2:
          Label: Rel Horiz Scroll
          Range: -1.000000 - -1.000000
          Resolution: 0 units/m
          Mode: relative
        Class originated from: 15. Type: XIValuatorClass
        Detail for Valuator 3:
          Label: Rel Vert Scroll
          Range: -1.000000 - -1.000000
          Resolution: 0 units/m
          Mode: relative
        Class originated from: 15. Type: XIScrollClass
        Scroll info for Valuator 2
          type: 2 (horizontal)
          increment: 15.000000
          flags: 0x0
        Class originated from: 15. Type: XIScrollClass
        Scroll info for Valuator 3
          type: 1 (vertical)
          increment: 15.000000
          flags: 0x0
```

~ $xinput list-props 15

```
Device 'SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad':
    Device Enabled (187):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (189): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    libinput Tapping Enabled (340): 1
    libinput Tapping Enabled Default (341): 0
    libinput Tapping Drag Enabled (342):    1
    libinput Tapping Drag Enabled Default (343):    1
    libinput Tapping Drag Lock Enabled (344):   0
    libinput Tapping Drag Lock Enabled Default (345):   0
    libinput Tapping Button Mapping Enabled (346):  1, 0
    libinput Tapping Button Mapping Default (347):  1, 0
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled (322):   1
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled Default (323):   0
    libinput Disable While Typing Enabled (348):    1
    libinput Disable While Typing Enabled Default (349):    1
    libinput Scroll Methods Available (326):    1, 1, 0
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled (327):   1, 0, 0
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled Default (328):   1, 0, 0
    libinput Click Methods Available (350): 1, 1
    libinput Click Method Enabled (351):    1, 0
    libinput Click Method Enabled Default (352):    1, 0
    libinput Middle Emulation Enabled (331):    0
    libinput Middle Emulation Enabled Default (332):    0
    libinput Accel Speed (333): 0.000000
    libinput Accel Speed Default (334): 0.000000
    libinput Left Handed Enabled (338): 0
    libinput Left Handed Enabled Default (339): 0
    libinput Send Events Modes Available (307): 1, 1
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled (308):    0, 0
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled Default (309):    0, 0
    Device Node (310):  "/dev/input/event5"
    Device Product ID (311):    2, 7
    libinput Drag Lock Buttons (324):   <no items>
    libinput Horizontal Scroll Enabled (325):   1
```

~ $gsettings list-recursively org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad

```
org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad click-method 'default'
org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad edge-scrolling-enabled false
org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad disable-while-typing true
org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad two-finger-scrolling-enabled true
org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad send-events 'enabled'
org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad speed 0.0
org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad scroll-method 'two-finger-scrolling'
org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad natural-scroll true
org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad middle-click-emulation false
org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad left-handed 'mouse'
org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad tap-to-click true
org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad tap-and-drag true
```

~ $gsettings list-recursively org.gnome.settings-
daemon.peripherals.touchpad.deprecated:/

```
org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.touchpad.deprecated horiz-scroll-enabled true
org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.touchpad.deprecated touchpad-enabled true
org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.touchpad.deprecated disable-while-typing false
org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.touchpad.deprecated motion-threshold -1
org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.touchpad.deprecated scroll-method 'two-finger-scrolling'
org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.touchpad.deprecated motion-acceleration -1.0
org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.touchpad.deprecated tap-to-click false
org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.touchpad.deprecated left-handed 'mouse'
org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.touchpad.deprecated natural-scroll false
```

~ $cat /proc/bus/input/devices

```
︙
I: Bus=0011 Vendor=0002 Product=0007 Version=01b1
N: Name="SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad"
P: Phys=isa0060/serio2/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/platform/i8042/serio2/input/input10
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=mouse0 event5 
B: PROP=5
B: EV=b
B: KEY=e520 10000 0 0 0 0
B: ABS=660800011000003
︙
```

I also tried these commands below however Touchpad does not work.

```
sudo apt-fast -y install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics
```

```
gsettings reset-recursively org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad
```

```
gsettings reset-recursively org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.touchpad
```

So what should I do to use Touchpad?

Thank you for reading this long question. I would appreciate any ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could enable ubuntu touchpad by following these steps.

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

You will see a line like

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT='quiet splash'
```

and edit here as follows.

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT='quiet splash psmouse.synaptics_intertouch=1'
```

Finally, run these commands to take effect.

```
sudo update-grub
sudo reboot
```